# Android ScrollView jumps around when resized

Tags: android, scrollview

I have a ScrollView that contains an number of other views (TextViews, ImageViews, etc.).  The ScrollView is taller than the screen.  I have an AsyncTask that updates the children of the ScrollView based on an http response.

I've discovered an interesting behavior that I can't figure out how to work around.  If I set any of the children's visibilities to View.INVISIBLE as part of the AsyncTask.onPostExecute(), everything works fine.

However, if I set any of the children's visibilities to View.GONE, the ScrollView jumps down from the top when onPostExecute() is called.  Exactly how far seems to vary.  I'm guessing that re-laying out the ScrollView is causing it to scroll away from the top for some reason.

So the question is: is there a way to either prevent or work around this behavior?

PS. Using ScrollView.jump(FOCUS_UP) as a workaround isn't ideal since that'll force the user to the top even if they had intended to scroll down.

**EDIT**: Actually, I was wrong.  The problem wasn't with a child view being marked gone, the problem was with a sibling view being marked gone and the ScrollView getting resized.  My ScrollView is inside a LinearLayout that also contains a Button.  When the button is set to GONE, the ScrollView gets resized to take up the available space, causing it to scroll away from the top.  Different cause, still looking for a workaround though if possible.

Comment: if View.INVISIBLE works why do you want to change it to View.GONE? my guess is that GONE is actually collapsing the view, triggering a complete redraw of your ScrollView and that INVISIBLE just hides it, but i cant say for sure

Comment: View.GONE is preferable for these views since I don't want blank space when the views are invisible.  Cheers, Mike

Comment: @emmby were you able to get a solution to this problem. I am facing similar issues.

Comment: @RiteshKadmawala sadly no :(

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. If layout jumping add tha following in ur top lever layout

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

Example:

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" >
```

Comment: I know we're not meant to +1, but thank you! This has been bugging me for ages!